# JavaScript How to add characters together to out put to a text box

Tags: javascript

I have buttons that pass a letter to a text box, Each time I press a button it puts that letter in the text box. I want to be able to add letters together and put them in the text box. If I press "Q" then "E"  I want the text box to contain QE. Right now if I Press Q it contains Q, but then I press E, it replaces the Q with the E, I need both. Also need a Clear button to get rid of all of them.

```
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
var AllLetters = ''
    AllLetters = AllLetters + clicked_id;
document.getElementById('letters').innerHTML="Letter: " + AllLetters;
var FindItData = 'findIT.asp?letters='+clicked_id;
//window.open(FindItData,"_self");

}

div>Press letters to find items:</div>
  <div>
<button id="Q" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Q</button> 
<button id="W" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">W</button> 
<button id="E" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">E</button>
```

...

Comment: you would want to set the textbox value to an array and the append that array in the subsequent button clicks.

Comment: Just append the new value: `document.getElementById('letters').innerHTML += clicked_id;`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click the button you you initialize the AllLetters variable.

All you need to do is to put var AllLetters = '' out side of the function so you don't lose track of the clicked letters.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to achieve what you want is to simply append the key to the text value as briskovitch suggested:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reply_click(clicked_id)
{
    document.getElementById('letters').value += clicked_id;
    var FindItData = 'findIT.asp?letters='+clicked_id;
    //window.open(FindItData,"_self");
}
</script>

<div>Press letters to find items:</div>
<input type="text" id='letters' value ="Letter: " />
<button id="Q" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Q</button> 
<button id="W" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">W</button> 
<button id="E" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">E</button>
```